# C pointer to character array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

### I would like to pass a character pointer ( to an array) to a function which will print the letters one by one.  For example I am using the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void string1(char *q)
{   
    while(*q)
    {
        printf(q++);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

main()
{
    char name[]= "hello";
    char *p=name;
    string1(p);
}
```

---

which prints:

- hello
- ello
- llo
- lo
- o

---

But I want it to print;

- h
- e
- l
- l
- o

---

I am unable to do it by using the variable q inside printf. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use a format string with `printf`. Passing strings with unknown values into the `printf` function can result in an [uncontrolled format string vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string). Printing a c-string with `printf` should be done like this: `printf("%s", string_pointer);`

That said, to print one character at a time you can use the `%c` formatter:

```
while(*q) {
    printf("%c\n", *(q++));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence: `printf(q++);` is wrong.
You have to print a character, only:

```
  printf("%c", *g++);
```

A better option:

```
 putchar(*g++);
```

In general, take in account that:

- `g` is the adress of an array of characters.
- To access the first character pointed by `g`, it is necessary to use the operator `*`, this way: `*g`.

The modifier `"%c"` in `printf()` gives you the possibility of printing a datum of type `char`.

Comment: Why is `putchar` better than `printf` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Because `putchar()` is intended to be used only with characters, so it can be expected that will be more efficient than `printf()`. The last one has to work around with a formatting string.

Comment: The `printf()` is also `variadic function`, so its optional arguments are subject to `default argument promotions` (in your case `char` value is promoted to `int`). The second thing is that `putchar()` may be implemented as macro or inlined, thus avoiding function's overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the first argument of `printf()`

By doing this:

```
printf(q++);
```

The application is behaving as if you want to print a string (because it keeps printing until it reaches `\0`), so what you are doing is equivalent to this;

```
printf("%s",q++);
```

But what you actually want is printing only the char at position `q`:

```
printf("%c",q++); // Prints only the char at q, then increment q
```